# A D wrapper around a C function

Tags: wrapper, child-process, d

Any problems with this D wrapper around `libcomcom_run_command()` C function from C library [libcomcom](https://github.com/vporton/libcomcom)?

Does it work as expected? Is it idiomatic? Is it the right way to do this?

```
module libcomcom_wrapper;

import std.string;
import std.algorithm.iteration : map;
import std.array : array;
import std.exception : ErrnoException;
import libcomcom;

string runCommand(string file, string[] argv, string[] envp, string input, int timeout = -1) {
    const(char*) output;
    size_t output_len;
    const char*[] childArgv = map!(s => s.toStringz)(argv).array;
    const char*[] childEnvp = map!(s => s.toStringz)(envp).array;
    immutable int res = libcomcom_run_command(input.ptr, input.length,
                                              &output, &output_len,
                                              file.toStringz, childArgv.ptr,
                                              childEnvp.ptr,
                                              timeout);
    if (res != 0) {
        throw new ErrnoException("Run command"); // TODO: Localization
    }
    import core.stdc.stdlib : free;
    scope(exit) free(cast(void*) output);
    return output[0..output_len].idup;
}
```

The code was taken [here](https://github.com/D-Programming-Deimos/libcomcom/blob/3cd76a25e2e4195b26bb1e642a3e4a7f1ede460d/deimos/libcomcom_wrapper.d).

Comment: I've discovered that I can use just `toStringz` instead of `s => s.toStringz`.

Comment: Need to add `~ null` after every `.array` (as otherwise there is no array terminator and it is undefined behavior probably)

Answer (score 1):

Nitpick: `map!(s => s.toStringz)(argv)` would be more idiomatic as `argv.map!toStringz`. Apart from that, your code looks very much correct. It should work as expected, and is indeed the way to do this.